# "academia" or "the academia"; "industry" or "the industry"

Tags: grammar

I wanted to know which one is correct? and Why?

Multimedia is attracting more attention in both the academia and the industry.

Multimedia is attracting more attention in both academia and industry.

Comment: _The industry_ = a particular industry. _Industry_ = industry in general. We wouldn't say _the academia_.

Comment: "The academy" can be used, meaning "academia".

Comment: Why someone gave negative to my question? What's wrong with it?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the second is correct.

"Academia" is a proper noun (although it is not always capitalised) and thus is incapable of being qualified by "the".

OED

> **Etymology:** Partly < classical Latin Acadēmīa academy n., and partly < classical Latin Acadēmus (ancient Greek Ἀκάδημος ), name of the Attic hero in whose grove Plato's Academy was situated;

***The** industry* can only be used if a particular industry has already been mentioned.

You intend "industry" to mean "industry in general", and therefore the unqualified, uncountable noun is required.

Comment: Surely when not capitalised _academia_ cannot be claimed to be a proper noun. It behaves similarly to _industry_ which is never capitalised except for effect (and sentence etc demands). It has the same semantic status as many similar overarching [words referencing] well-known, establishment institutions. It takes the prestigious null article.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting, but the difficulty is that A/academia never -for large values of "never" -  takes "an/the", whether capitalised of not. A/academia seems to be [in] a set of its own. The only other words that approach this are proper nouns (I know that "He is not **the** John I mean." is possible.) It is people's **use of capitalisation** that is irregular, and does not resemble the countable/uncountable "industry" at all: it seems to be a unique eponym.(Compare "I have **a** hoover (vacuum cleaner)" and "I have **a** Hoover.(something made by Hoover", which work as expected.)

Comment: The noun _nuclear_ is certainly used by, for instance, politicians and is listed in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nuclear#Noun), and (with an 'informal' caveat for the time being) Collins. OED may be a little behind. // Many sports use a non-capitalised non-count usage for the organisations; ' "[I]sn't it good to have football back again? Isn't it a sign we are returning to normal[?]" writes columnist Doug Robinson.' // We also have 'suburbia', the institutions 'vaudeville', 'acting', 'grunge' (He's into grunge cf the grunge scene) ... there are many mandatorily anarthrous ns.